# Getting mutliple threads and their latest post from a database using one query

Tags: mysql

I want to code a forum with subforums and need to create an overview of a subforum displaying the latest post of a thread in a html-table.

I have two mysql tables:

**forum_threads:**

id  int(10)
forumid     int(10)
title   varchar(80)
accesslevel     int(2)
locked  enum('yes', 'no')

**forum_post:**

id  int(10)
threadid    int(10)
userid  int(10)
posted  datetime
edited  datetime
message     text

My query looks like that:

```
SELECT * FROM `forum_threads` LEFT JOIN `forum_post`
ON (forum_post.threadid = forum_threads.id)
WHERE forumid='$secfid'
AND accesslevel<='$secuserlevel'
ORDER BY forum_post.posted DESC
LIMIT $qStart,$ppp
```

Where $secfid is the id of the subforum.

My problem ist that the result set contains all posts and because of that, each thread is contained as many times as its number of posts.
Each thread should only be there once and only with the latest post in it's result row.

I could solve it with an additional subquery but I wanted to ask if there is a better way to do it.

I also found something like this on stackoverflow:

```
SELECT * FROM `forum_post` fp
JOIN `forum_threads` ft
ON (fp.threadid = ft.id) WHERE forumid=1
AND accesslevel<='100'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM forum_post fp2
    JOIN forum_threads ft2
    ON fp2.threadid = ft2.id
    WHERE ft.forumid = ft2.forumid
    AND fp.posted < fp2.posted
) LIMIT 0,20
```

This returns all the desired information but only from the thread with the latest post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it by joining on a subselect that retrieved the latest post from each thread.

The subselect will give you back the latest posted date in each thread.  This can then be used to get thread and post data:

```
SELECT
    thread.title,
    post.text
FROM
    forum_thread thread

-- Get latest post from each thread 
JOIN (
    SELECT      
        MAX(post.posted) as posted,
        post.threadid
    FROM
        forum_post post

    JOIN 
        forum_thread thread
    ON 
        post.threadid = thread.id

    -- Limit the forum and security levels  
    WHERE
        thread.forumid = '$secfid'
        AND thread.accesslevel <= '$secuserlevel'       
    GROUP BY
        post.threadid

) latest_post
ON 
    thread.id = latest_post.threadid

-- Get post data for the latest post
JOIN
    forum_post post
ON
    latest_post.threadid = post.threadid
    AND latest_post.posted = post.posted

LIMIT
    $qStart, $ppp;
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very close to what I want. The only problem I have now is that I'm getting an error: #1054 - Unknown column 'latest_post.posted' in 'on clause' when I'm using MAX().

Comment: Ups, forgot to add the alias to the MAX() function.  Should be ok now with `MAX(post.posted) as posted` added to the subselect.